# Google sign in API implemention

Tags: android, google-api

This should be a simple enough question. When implementing a Google sign in Api do I have to update the Sha key and the actual app info on the Google development console for every version of the app? The signin of my app works for some versions and doesn't in other versions without changing any of the in app code. Could this just be a bug or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**: No

**Long Answer**: Usually there are two variants of android applications, debug/development version and release/production version. You have to always sign your application before it can run on any android platform.

For debug variants, this signing is performed automatically by android studio with a default debug fingerprint key whereas for release variant you have to create it manually.

Now, while setting your **Google SignIn API** in Google console, you have to provide the SHA key (or all keys) with which your app will be signed.

In above case, both the debug and release SHA keys when added, all the application versions which will be signed using those keys will work with that API.

For more information, please see this detailed guide.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth